# Android Turkish Character "UTF-8"

Tags: android

I use "UTF-8" for charset in order to contain Turkish characters. In messaging part it is OK and turkish characters is shown but, with same system ,user brief part does not encode turkish character properly. User brief async part code snippet:

```
public class ServerKullaniciDurum extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        String durum;
        String query, charset;

        public ServerKullaniciDurum(String durum) {
            this.durum = durum;
            charset = "UTF-8";
            String param1 = "id";
            String param2 = "status";
            try {
                query = String.format("param1=%s&param2=%s", URLEncoder.encode(param1, charset), URLEncoder.encode(param2, charset));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            URLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                Log.i("tago" , "durum" + durum);
                Log.i("tago" , "durum encode " + URLEncoder.encode(durum,charset));
                connection = new URL("http://www.ceng.metu.edu.tr/~e1818871/shappy/my_status?id="
                        + params[0] + "&status=" + URLEncoder.encode(durum, charset)).openConnection();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);

            OutputStream output;
            try {
                output = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                output.write(query.getBytes(charset));
                InputStream inputstream = connection.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "calaba";
        }
    }
```

What is this reason ? How can i overcome it ?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?